# Probability that two objects fall on the same person conditional that that person is not me

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Object $A$ can fall on one of $k$ individuals and object $B$ can fall on one of $m$ individuals. If I am a member of both group $k$ and $m$, then my payoff is:

$$
\frac{1}{km}X+\frac{1}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{m} \right)Y+\frac{1}{m}\left(1-\frac{1}{k} \right)Z+\left(1-\frac{1}{k} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{m} \right)U.
$$

However, my payoff in the $4^{\rm th}$ case, $U$ depends on whether one person got both objects or if both objects went to separate people. So if I am the only one who is a part of both groups, then trivially there is $0$ percent chance that both objects went to the same person.

So my question is, what is the probability that the object goes to two persons conditional on the fact that I didn't win either of the two objects? Lets just say that my payoff if two objects go to the same person is $T$ and my payoff if they go to separate persons is $P$, therefore clearly $U$ is some function of $T$ and $P$.

Assume there are $r$ people apart from me who are in both groups, obviously, $r$ must be smaller than both $m$ and $k$.

Just to be clear, what is the probability that the objects fall on the same person conditional on the fact they didn't fall on me?

Comment: Well, excluding you there are $(k-1)+(m-1)-(r-1)=k+m-r-1$ people in total, and there are $r-1$ people in the intersection, so $\frac {r-1}{k+m-r-1}$.

Comment: @lulu That looks to me like the probability of sampling a person who is in both groups... not the probability that somebody else gets both objects.

Comment: Right, sorry.  But the same principle applies.  Your conditional space is just the same as the space in the original problem with one person deleted from the intersection.